# Team Foundation Server with Command-Line not working

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to connect to the Team Foundation Server from command line.

It dose not working in Command-Line but working with GUI (eclipse,VS)

I can't determinant the error

when I call `tf get` I always get this message `"All files up to date."` and no files that downloaded

Can anyone give me a full tutorial step by step to check my work

Answer (score 2):

- Start VS developer command prompt
- Switch to the folder where your workspace is mapped
- type "tf get"

If you expect to get anything, but it says `"All files up to date."` try:

- tf get /force

This will download the files, no matter if you should have them already.

It is normal behaviour of TFS that after getting the sources, it will only download files that changed on TFS (!!!) after last get. If you deleted them in Windows Explorer or removed the ReadOnly flag and edited the file, TFS will not recognize these changes and therefor a get will deliver nothing.